Forgot the name of the film. Teen rides a motorcycle and becomes a hero
Along time ago, I saw a film - not sure if it was tv-film, episode or a feature - where a teen was always being bulied in high school, and then, I do not know how, the teen learns (or was it a superpower?) how to ride really well a bike, and helps people, to the point that he becomes a hero. I clearly remember his black helmet, which helped him conceal his identity, and a green helmet. Then, the pretty girl of the high school tries to date the hero. The boy in his everyday life is bullied, and the girl is not the least interested in him, only the hero, without knowing that they are the same. 
I saw this in the 90's, and the film was in American English, and as time passed by, I forgot the name...
Any help would be appreciated.

The Misfits? Super Hoodie!

By 'bike' do you mean a bicycle or a motorcycle? Or something inbetween? (And BTW, what did the kid look like?)

@cde the british series? It's too recent. what I saw was in the 90's... ;)

@Walt I mean a motorcycle. I don't know why, but I always pictured him similar to a young Matt Dillon in style... not sure why. =D

Could it be 'the wraith' with charlie sheen?

@Darren isn't that with a car?

I'm gonna go out on a limb (as you did not mention it being a musical) and say Grease 2

A new arrival comes in the form of clean-cut English student Michael Carrington (Maxwell Caulfield), the cousin of Sandy Olsson (the character played by Olivia Newton-John in the first Grease movie). Michael quickly becomes smitten with Stephanie, despite the gentle warning of the sole remaining lead character from the first film, Frenchy (Didi Conn), who is returning to Rydell High to get her diploma was told about Michael's arrival in a letter from Sandy and helps Michael get settled into the school atmosphere as Sandy's behest. Michael takes an instant liking to Stephanie, but Frenchy tells him that she will not date him since he is not a T-Bird.
At the local bowling alley, a competitive game ('Score Tonight') turns sour due to the animosity between Johnny and Stephanie. Johnny flirts with Stephanie's friend and fellow Pink Lady, Paulette Rebchuck (Lorna Luft), to make Stephanie jealous, and she retaliates by kissing the next man who walks in the door, which happens to be Michael. Bemused by this unexpected kiss, Michael attempts to ask her out the next day at an audition for the school talent show, but discovers that she has a very specific vision of her ideal man ('Cool Rider'). He realizes that he will only win her affection if he turns himself into a cool rider, and begins saving up for a motorcycle by selling completed homework assignments to the academically-challenged T-Birds. Michael buys the bike, fixes it up and spends all his spare time after school learning to ride it.
Following an unusual, largely interactive biology lesson ('Reproduction') given by new substitute teacher Mr. Stuart (Tab Hunter), a gang of rival motorcyclists called the Cycle Lords (led by Balmudo, who also played "Leo" in the first film and also a rival of the T-Birds) surprise the T-Birds at the bowling alley. Before the fight starts, a lone anonymous biker, wearing all black clothing as well as a motorcycle helmet and dark goggles to cover his face, appears and defeats the enemy gang, performing impressive stunts and leaping over police cars to disappear into the night ('Who's That Guy?'). Stephanie is instantly fascinated with the stranger.





The story is similar, but the time period is a bit off. The film, from what I can remember, was set in 80's or 90's. Is there a film which may be an 'updated' version of 'Grease 2'?

Also, I don't think it was a musical.

I've just remembered that a similar situation happened in the film I'm looking for. There was a bike showdown, but it occurred in an alley.
